# Linking Oracle and C#

Tags: c#, oracle11g

I  just wanted to know how I can link Oracle to C# ;
I installed C# 2008 and ADO.net 11g and oracle 11g ;
But I can't get my data from data base when I use C# ;
What should I do ?

Comment: please provide more details, perhaps a code sample, of what you did so far

Comment: I think it doesn't matter to have a code sample

Comment: I told I can't get my data I mean I can't connect to my database through c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparently I can not post 2 links. [Here's](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle) some help to get you going with the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to `System.Data.OracleClient` to your project. Then you can use the `OracleConnection` and `OracleCommand` objects just like you used the `SqlClient` ones.

You can check out a nice example of a generic data access layer [here](http://aspalliance.com/837).